# Facebook JS API: Is it possible streamPublish to many targets at once?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to make my app publish to all my friend's walls.

From what I read in [the API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish), the `streamPublish` method only allows you to publish to one person at a time.

What I'm doing is fetching all the friends with `FB.Facebook.apiClient.friends_get` then a for on the reuslts, and a `streamPublish` for every one.

This however seems hacky.

Is it possible to `streamPublish` to many targets at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked on the facebook forums too, the answers I've got is that it isn't possible.